# Рендер рук поверх с тенями стен в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

назрел вопрос по поводу рендера рук с оружием персонажа.

Делаю шутер от 1-го лица, когда персонаж стоит в плотную к стене, оружие пропадает в стене. Фиксанул данную проблему с помощью 2-й камеры, то есть основная камера рендерила все кроме рук, а 2-я камера рендерила онли руки. Но при использовании этого решения тени на руки не накладывается, если встать в темный угол где не должно быть света, то руки с оружием светятся как фонари.

Сразу спасибо тем кто поможет исправить данную проблему)